# [Python pandas]:ValueError: could not convert string to float: '#DIV/0!'

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
trans=pd.read_csv("steam3.csv")

y=trans["price"]
x=trans[["positive_ratings","c.owners"]]
from sklearn import linear_model
mymodel=linear_model.LinearRegression()
mymodel.fit(x,y)
mymodel.coef_
```

There is an error:ValueError: could not convert string to float: '#DIV/0!' However,those columes are all float in csv file.

csv sample:
[image]

Comment: Please post an example of what the CSV file data looks like

Comment: Your formula in excel is dividing by zero somewhere: `#DIV/0!` you need to add`IFERROR` to your formula.

Comment: @It_is_Chris i dont get it. where should i add IFERROR? the excel file?

Comment: @Needhelp `#DIV/0!` is an error in excel. In one of your columns you are dividing a number by zero, which returns `#DIV/0!` Whatever formula you are using to get the error you need to add `IFERROR` to it and replace the error with whatever is appropriate for your dataset.

Comment: @It_is_Chris i have delected the records with #DIV/0! but it shows an error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 33-34: invalid continuation byte

Answer (score 2):

If you simply use:
trans=pd.read_csv("steam3.csv", na_values= '#DIV/0!' )
This is a nice solution as it converts your text to NaN which won't affect your floats

Comment: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').